# Proving that the derivative of an even function is odd: intermediate steps.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was shown a proof that when an even function is differentiable, its derivative is an odd function.  It was proven as:

$$\begin{align}
f'(-x) &= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(-x+h) -f(-x)}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}\\ 
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{-h}\\
&= -\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h}\\
&= -f'(x)\end{align}$$

I am currently stuck at the 4th equation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You may want to [typeset your post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111246/proving-that-the-derivative-of-an-odd-function-is-even?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is an even function, then $f(x)=f(-x)$, which is why $f(-x+h)=f(x-h).$ Then, if we are to assume that the derivative exists, we can simply replace $h$ with $-h$ and the limit stays the same as $h\to0$.

Comment: Sorry, i'm sure i'm on the wrong track, but does have anything that taking h from the left doesn't make a difference?

Comment: If the derivative exists, it doesn't matter. If it does matter, then by changing $h$ to $-h$, you also change the direction of approach.