# Let $F(x)= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt$. Show that if f is even, F is odd.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, derivatives, even-and-odd-functions

I have been working on this question. I know that if a function is even then f(x)=f(-x). Take derivative of both sides and you get f'(x)=-f'(-x), hence f' is odd. However, I am not sure how to go about this one with the integration and different independent variable $t$. We are also given a hint: apply the u-substitution u=-t. Any help or hints is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: OK. You start by writing down what $F(-x)$ is (ie what you get when you plug in $-x$ to the expression for $F$). This should be an integral, so that means you can use a $u$-substitution on it, and hence you can use the hint. If that still doesn't make sense, please try to give some more detail on what part you don't understand.

Comment: $F'(x)$ is basically $f(x)$. So you are asking if $F'(x)$ is even, show that $F(x)$ is odd. I think this site already has answers to that. Check this out -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111246/proving-that-the-derivative-of-an-odd-function-is-even?rq=1

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen this helped, thank you!

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Consider $F(-x)=\int^{-x}_{0}f(t)dt$. From there you can use your substitution that $u=-t \Rightarrow du=-dt$ which then gives

$$F(-x)=\int^{-x}_{0}f(t) dt=-\int^{x}_{0}f(-u)du=-\int^{x}_{0}f(u)du=-F(x)$$

Which is exactly your definition of 'oddness': $F(-x)=-F(x)$.

Comment: This greatly helped, thank you!